# How to install the Qt mobility?

Tags: qt, symbian, contacts, nokia, qt-mobility

i have installed Qt 4.6.2 and developing the application for symbian.
Now i want use Qt mobility API for accessing the contacts.. how can i install the Qt mobility and acces the API..

my build environment is windows XP :)

Thanks

Comment: Can some one tell how can we  install it in Mac?

Comment: use, NokiaQt SDK for MAC..By default NokiaQT SDK comes with Mobility support

Answer (score 2):

Download the source + Symbian binary package from http://qt.nokia.com/products/appdev/add-on-products/catalog/4/new-qt-apis/mobility and unzip one of the contained qt-mobility-1.0.0-epoc32 packages to your epocroot. You may also want to install convenienceheaders.zip package to get nice Qt style headers. The download package also contains SIS files for installing the Qt Mobility libraries to target devices.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to use the (almost-final) Nokia Qt SDK. It includes everything you need, without any additional hassle.

It is a RC, the last stage before a stable release: [link](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/e920da1a-5b18-42df-82c3-907413e525fb/Nokia_Qt_SDK.html)

Comment: And its been final for some time now - use it, its a huge step forward!